# ImageJ alternative for Ruby on Rails Development

Tags: image-processing, image-comparison

I have an analysis management web system developed using Ruby on Rails and I need to analyse an uploaded image in my system. Using Java I used to have ImageJ included im my projects. Since I'm new in Ruby on Rails I don't know any library/gem to manage Image processing.

Do you know any image processing gem for Rails like ImageJ on Java?